# How to send a date value to read-only input boxes using VBA Selenium webdriver

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I ran into an issue with a read-only calendar input box. I need to send a date value to it through Selenium VBA. Here is the snippet of the HTML code I'm looking at:

```
<input class="dxeEditArea dxeEditAreaSys" id="pickupDate_I" 
name="ctl00$ctl00$MainPane$Content$MainContent$OPUserControl$pickupDate" 
onfocus="ASPx.EGotFocus('pickupDate')" onblur="ASPx.ELostFocus('pickupDate')" 
onchange="ASPx.EValueChanged('pickupDate')" type="text" readonly="">
```

I put a solution I ended up using as a JS code below as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I ended up using: run a JavaScript code to replace the value in the field, rather than using SendKeys. This way we bypass readonly attribute that affects .SendKeys, but using .Value inside the script works:

```
driver.ExecuteScript ("document.getElementById('pickupDate_I').value = '01/01/2010'")
```

Answer (score 0):

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='pickupDate_I'])).sendKeys("your value");

Comment: Thank you, when I enter this line with VBA syntax: driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[@id='pickupDate_I']).SendKeys "01/09/2021"      I get an error that highlights "01" and the error msg says: Compile error: Expected: list separator or ) . Not sure what the problem might be here.

Comment: I got this error message resolved with updated syntax, however this line doesn't do anything: driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[@id='pickupDate_I']").SendKeys "01/09/2021"      I suspect this is because the initial HTML has a read-only tag at the end. What would we a way to bypass it?